# property appendChild undefined when trying to insert a script tag

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to inject an SCRIPT tag into a react component to load `cookieBot` library.

Here you have my component.

```
class CookieDeclarationSection extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      title: "Cookie declaration",
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    console.log(script)
    script.id = "CookieDeclaration"
    script.src = "https://consent.cookiebot.com/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX"
    script.type = "text/javascript"
    script.async = true
    this.instance.appendChild(script)
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="citation__result">
        <WideScreenOnlyHeading title={this.state.title} />
        <div style={{margin: "16px"}}>
          {/*!-- insert SCRIPT TAG here */}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However I keep getting

> Cannot read property appendChild of undefined

. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: `this.instance` is undefined...

Comment: What are you expect? You set to this.instance nothing. May be you want make this: document.body.appendChild(script);

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I could I missed that!, I actually ended up using `document.getElementById('declarationWrapper').appendChild(script)`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [react-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-safe) package to append your script using only jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Safe from "react-safe"

const CookieDeclarationSection = () => (
  <div className="citation__result">
    <WideScreenOnlyHeading title="Cookie declaration" />
    <div style={{margin: "16px"}}>
      <Safe.script type="text/javascript" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX" async></Safe.script>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```